# Status reason not available when trying to add it as a column to a view (Microsoft Dynamics 365)

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I'm new to Microsoft Dynamics 365 and I've been trying to add the status reason field on the Activity entity as a column to one of my views but for some reason I'm unable to find it on the list of options to pick from.

I've searched around and thought maybe it was due to the `Searchable` field is set to **No** but [this article](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics365apps/posts/kb-understanding-dynamics-365-field-s-searchable-property) points that it shouldn't matter.

What is the reason for the status reason field not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamics CRM Activity is so complex, a single Activity (Activity Pointer) entity can store a variety of Activity types like Email, Appointment, Task, Phonecall, etc and even custom Activity types are possible. So all these can have a variety of Status Reasons (`statuscode`) under different Status (`statecode`). Probably MS don't want to over complicate it by allowing them to show in parent `Activity` container table.

I tried in XrmToolBox fetchxml builder and the result is unexpected.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" >
  <entity name="activitypointer" >
    <attribute name="activitytypecode" />
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <attribute name="statuscodename" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="statecode" />
    <attribute name="statecodename" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Email got the **Pending Send** as 6 (Status Reason). This is the reason why it's not available in view columns.

> [image]
>   [image]

If you see the different combinations, lets say for Activity, Appointment & Email - clearly **Status Reason** is odd man out.

> [image]
>   [image]

[Reference](https://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/status-and-status-reason-values-in-dynamics-crm-2013/)

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. I appreciate the help!